# Issues using Beautifulsoup to navigate to the next page

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am scrapping zillows website to gather data on house listings.I gathered all the data on the first page.

I want to gather data on the second place.So I want to click the link to the 'next button', which will navigate me to page 2, page 3, and so on. I used the Inspect feature of Chrome to locate the html structure of the 'next button'. It has the following structure

```
<a href=”/homes/recently_sold/house_type/47164_rid/0_singlestory/37.720288,-121.859322,37.601788,-121.918888_rect/12_zm/2_p/” class=”on” onclick=”SearchMain.changePage(2);return false;” id=”yui_3_18_1_1_1525048531062_27962">Next</a>
```

Then I used Beautiful Soup’s find_all method and filter on tag “a” and class “on”.

> next_button = soup.find_all("a", class_="on")

I am getting an empty list.Any inputs?